# Add Tracking API in Paypal - Authorization failed

Tags: authentication, magento, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to add tracking number and order status in my sandbox account through tracking API but getting "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions" error. Anyone have any idea why this error happens? Below are my codes and response from paypal -

API request

```
$clientId = 'my client id';
$secretKey = 'my secret key';
$token = $this->getAccessToken($clientId, $secretKey);
$transaction = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\TransactionSearchResultInterfaceFactory')->create()->addOrderIdFilter($currentOrder->getId())->getFirstItem();
$transactionId = $transaction->getData('txn_id');
$postfields = [
    'trackers' =>
    [
        0 =>
        [
            'transaction_id' => $transactionId,
            'tracking_number' => $currentOrderTrackingNumber,
            'status' => 'SHIPPED',
            'carrier' => 'OTHER',
            'carrier_name_other' => 'SCS Logistics'
        ]
    ]
];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers-batch",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postfields),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

Response from paypal

```
Array
(
[tracker_identifiers] => Array
    (
    )

[errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => NOT_AUTHORIZED
                [message] => Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => /trackers/1/transaction_id
                                [value] => 42L93730906985049
                                [location] => body
                                [issue] => USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED
                                [description] => You are not authorized to add or modify tracking number for this transaction
                            )

                    )

                [links] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[links] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [href] => https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers-batch
                [rel] => self
                [method] => POST
                [encType] => application/json
            )

    )
)
```

I already contacted support and they added required permission but it's not working. Please if anyone have any idea about it help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the permission, wait 9 hours after it was added or force a refresh of your access_token, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841785/paypal-transaction-search-api-permission-denied-no-permission-for-the-requeste/60853246#60853246

Comment: It's already past 9 hours. And token gets generate as new every time I sent api requests

Comment: Tokens are cached for 9 hours. But if that is not the issue, try creating a new transaction via https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client using the same clientID on the SDK line as in your PHP code, and attempt to add tracking for that new transaction

Comment: I am using paypal express checkout on a Magento store

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: hello how do you solve it, i face the same problem, thank you reply