# How to access all transactions my PayPal account received via Api?

Tags: api, paypal

I have a bussiness account on PayPal and I need to use the API to get all transactions (money that other people paid me on PayPal) in my account. So far I managed to obtain the `access_token` using the API however when I try to access the transactions I get an error. My code (PHP) is below:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(

    "http" => array(
    
        "ignore_errors" => true,
        "method"  => "GET",
        "header" => array(
        
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer " . "access_token"
            
        )
        
    )
    
));

echo file_get_contents("https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2022-01-01T00:00:00-0700&end_date=2022-01-12T23:59:59-0700&fields=all",0,$context);
```

I always get this as the response:

```
{"localizedMessage":"No permission for the requested operation. ","suppressed":[],"name":"PERMISSION_DENIED","message":"No permission for the requested operation. ","details":[{"field":null,"value":null,"location":null,"issue":"No permission for the requested operation. "}],"information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/permissions/","debug_id":"45cb548f7bddb"}
```

I followed the information link in the response but it ends up in a 404 page. Maybe what I need is not the transactions API but I have no idea what part of the API would grant me access to all the payments people made to me... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [the app/clientid](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) you are using, have you enabled the necessary permission?

[image]

After enabling and saving that permission, the change may take up to 9 hours to have an effect if you have a cached access token from previous oauth2 calls to use the API. But, you can simply [terminate your old access token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60853246/2069605) to thus get a new one instead of waiting 9 hours.

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications  --> this link is not working, can you share the latest link to get access transaction history

Comment: The link is correct. If you want to navigate manually, go to https://developer.paypal.com , Log into Dashboard, My Apps & Credentials.