# PayPal Sandbox API alway results in Unauthorized error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created a test sandbox app and took the Client ID and Secret and ran the call

```
curl -v POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "CLIENT ID:SECRET" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I get the access_token from the response which I then use to try and run some basic API calls, such as

```
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer access_token"
```

But no matter which API call I make, I am always seeing some sort of unauthorized message (depending on the API that I called).

Any ideas?  Am I missing something here?  From what I figure, I should be able to make authorized API calls.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of the response I get from a transactions call

```
{"name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error","rel":"information_link"}]}
```

Here is the response I get form a Payouts call...

```
{"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred.","debug_id":"cfde17663b411","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors","links":[]}
```

I don't get an authorization error when calling the catalogs/product call...

```
{"products":[],"links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products?page_size=10&page=1","rel":"self","method":"GET"}]}
```

Comment: For v1/reporting/transactions in particular, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60853246/2069605 . For others, give an example request and response.

Comment: I updated the question to add some examples of the responses I am getting.

Comment: Both transactions and payouts require enabling a permission in the app. The Catalog/products text shown is not an error.

Comment: They are enabled... https://ibb.co/56n6vjB

Comment: And the token needs to be terminated from cache after enabling them, per the above linked answer. Meanwhile if other API calls return an error, give a full example with the complete request and the complete response.

Comment: I have made a couple tokens for this app since I first started trying to get this to work.  Perhaps it would be better to delete the app and make a new one and go from there?

Comment: There is no need. Terminate your current access token so it is no longer cached. Permission denied errors for APIs other than Transaction Reports and Payouts will be a separate issue, so that needs examples.

Comment: I don't want to make this comment thread too long... but when I try to terminate the token I get {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}.

Comment: Seriously? `curl -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/terminate -d "token=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_TOKEN"`

Comment: yup, seriously.  I think I will delete this sandbox app and start again.  Something is not right.

Comment: Deleted the app and created a new one, got the Transaction Search API to work, but the Payouts is still giving me a AUTHORIZATION_ERROR