# API for retrieving the current balance of my PayPal account?

Tags: paypal

Is there an API for retrieving the current balance of my PayPal account? Is there a way I can securely query my PayPal account and retrieve the total balance in my account?

I want to do this to create a "we have x out of y for our monthly quota" type things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transaction Search API has [a method to check balances](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/transaction-search/#link-checkbalances).

To use it, first enable the Transaction Search permission in [your REST App settings](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications).

- If you requested an API access token in the 9 hours prior to enabling that permission, either [terminate that access token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60853246/2069605) or wait up to 9 hours for it to expire from cache.