# Get all transactions from clients account using PayPal API

Tags: php, paypal

How can I get all transactions from client's account?

I have the client's access token & refresh token (it solved).

How can I connect to their account via API?

Can I get all transactions?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh and 1 question per question please

Answer (score 0):

To use [the transaction search API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/) as a 3rd party, you need to be a PayPal partner and be given access to this.

To use it as a first party (with a client ID and secret belonging to the account), the permission needs to be enabled on the corresponding REST app configuration, and [any existing access_token refreshed from cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841785/paypal-transaction-search-api-permission-denied-no-permission-for-the-requeste/60853246#60853246)

In general the best way to get a full list of transactions from an account is to go to its Reports and do an Activity Download in CSV format, for import.

Comment: I have business acccount. It is normal? 
My clients have connecting to my app.

 
> Download in CSV format, for import.

how can I use API for this?

Comment: Not an API, it's in each account's own web interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need for clients account only.

Comment: The reports activity download as a CSV file is available in each client's account for them to download, and you can then import it.

Comment: I have clients access token  and how can I import this files?