# PAYEE_NOT_ENABLED_FOR_CARD_PROCESSING - Error when creating an order with payment information to be processed with Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting the following error when attempting to create an Order in a Live Application:

```
{
      "issue": "PAYEE_NOT_ENABLED_FOR_CARD_PROCESSING",
      "description": "Payee account is not setup to be able to process card payments. Please contact PayPal customer support."
}
```

I did not get this error when building out the API in the Sandbox environment, I've tried to contact support multiple times, at this time I've spoken to over 5 different support representatives and bounced around between various departments but no one seems to be able to point me in the right direction as to how I can address this account restriction.

I'm sending in the following request:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
-H "PayPal-Request-Id: ######" \
-d '{
  "intent": "AUTHORIZE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "d9f80740-38f0-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b",
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      }
    }
  ],
  "payment_source": {
    "card": {
      "number": "4111111111111111",
      "expiry": "2023-02",
      "billing_address": {
        "postal_code": "95131",
        "country_code": "US"
      }
    },
    "stored_credential": {
      "payment_initiator": "MERCHANT",
      "payment_type": "ONE-TIME",
      "usage": "DERIVED"
    }
  }
}'
```

The expectation is that users can enter in their card details through a Phone IVR that data gets passed off to Paypal in the form of an order for a transaction to processed. I tested the workflow in the Sandbox and it worked just fine, but for some reason it just does not work in the Live App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrate card payments documentation [has a note that says](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate#link-enableyouraccounttoacceptcardpayments):

> - Before you go live, you need to [complete production onboarding](https://www.paypal.com/bizsignup/entry/product/ppcp) to be eligible to process cards with your live PayPal account.

Comment: I clicked the link and was automatically redirected to a screen with the following message:

Welcome to PayPal

Thanks for choosing PayPal as your payments provider.
You can now accept payments and manage your transactions anytime on PayPal.com

I launch another test and it still gives me the same error, I also have the Accept payments and ACDC permissions enabled.

Comment: Were the permissions changed recently - within the past 9 hours? If so you need to terminate the access token: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841785/paypal-transaction-search-api-permission-denied-no-permission-for-the-requeste/60853246#60853246  (Look at the `scopes` being returned in your oauth call to check, compare the values in sandbox to live).  And if that's not it, update your question with the entire API response you are getting when attempting to process in live.

Comment: I'm generating a new token with each request in the workflow I have built out. I was able to manage to get it to work. I worked with support to put together a completely new account and walked through the verification steps and tested a live payment and it worked, so I retraced the verification steps on my end and it ended up working.

You need to go to the 'Paypal Checkout' product and go through the Get Started process and then it should clear the permission issue. For some weird reason, you have to do this first before validating on the Dev dashboard.

Comment: It returns a cached token 9 hours after changes, so you may have been requesting one but that does not mean a new one was being generated if you had just enabled the permission/scope, hence what I pointed out above