# Paypal REST API Error "REQUIRED SCOPE MISSING"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the Paypal REST API and have unchecked "Disputes" and checked "Payouts" within the appropriate Sandbox application in my developer console.

However the (allowed) scope returned with the access token is always:

```
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/update-seller openid 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/read-seller 
https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks
```

regardless of my settings in the developer console, hence I am not able to use (test) "Payouts"
(Naturally it gives the response `REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING, Access token does not have required scope.`)

(I have not checked for my live application, but I would assume it's the same. If not, I will update here later)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access tokens are cached for 9 hours. You can [terminate your existing token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841785/paypal-transaction-search-api-permission-denied-no-permission-for-the-requeste/60853246#60853246) so it refreshes.

Then it will have the newly set scopes.

Comment: it was indeed working this morning, so I have no evidence to the contrary and accepting this answer as the solution! Thanks for the hint towards the cache time of access tokens. I will keep that in mind for the future!